# Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest'

Tags: vuejs2

Using vue cli i have created a project and then added:

```
vue add unit-jest
```

When i try to run the test namely:

```
npm run test:unit
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest'
```

I am using vue cli 4.5.9 and node v12.19.0 and npm 6.14.8

The cli-plugin-unit-jest is installed as part of unit-jest so not sure why its erroring? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

So I did,

npm install -g @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest

that fixed it.